# Stretch/Shrink an object according to two other vertex groups

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, edit-mode, shape-keys

Consider this cube between the character's hands:

[image]

I'd like to make it automatically stretch when the arms move:

[image]

These hands are a part of a rigged character, so they don't have their own origins. How can I achieve this? Supposedly there are multiple ways to implement this, but I can't figure out even one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a bone for each hand. Parent your object to the armature with the *With Empty Group* mode, then assign the vertices of your object to the group they are supposed to be part of, decrease the *Weight* value along the obect:

[image]

Now when you move the hand bone, it deforms the object:

[image]